# Google script stops working after copying and authorizing

Tags: google-sheets

After making a copy of my perfectly working google sheet, together with the script that comes with it; the script itself does not work anymore in the copy. 
I go through the steps of authorizing it as an app but it seems to hang when i run it on the copy. It times out after 540 odd seconds. It seems to be having trouble with DriveApp.createFolder (exectution time 540 seconds). Yet i have not changed anything in the script, works fine on the original one.
Here is the script, im pretty sure everything is fine here, it just doesn't want to work as soon as you make a copy of it. I need to make copies of this sheet for each person in my team but i can't at the moment.

```
    function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,2).getValue();
  var time = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(4,2).getValue();
  var site = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2).getValue();
  // iterate through all sheets in the spreadsheet and rename them according to cell B2
  for( var j = 0 ; j < sheets.length; j++) {
    var sourceSheet = sheets[j];
    // get contents of cell B2
    var newSheetName = sourceSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
    // rename sheet
    sourceSheet.setName(newSheetName);
  }
  // create a folder from the named SNOWSURVEYS with date
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('SNOWSURVEYS' + '_' + date + '_'+ site);
    // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
    fileName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() + ".csv";
    // convert all available sheet data to csv format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
    folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
    var folderID = folder.getId();
    var folderName = folder.getName();
    var ui = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Your files have are in your google drive in a folder called ' + folder);
    var p = ui.createVerticalPanel();
    ui.add(p);
    p.add(ui.createAnchor('Click here to go straight to your files ',folder.getUrl()));
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(ui)
  }
```

[Execution transcript printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQbnG.png)

Comment: I would change ` var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,2).getValue();` to get a specifically named sheet's values.  Also, is there valid data in the cells where you are retrieving the date and site variables?  Maybe put this line in front of the one where you create the folder to make sure you have valid values: `Browser.msgBox('SNOWSURVEYS' + '_' + date + '_'+ site);` or set a break point there and use the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for that, i think there was an invalid format used for date, which is what was causing the problem